# Add a class to this div and remove it after a while in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?
What I am trying to do is, when on click of a div then add a class "active" and remove it after a while. When adding active class to it's parent div then I am going to play with some content within it's div.

I am able to do it in jQuery but I am unable to do exactly in Javascript.

This is the code I wrote in jQuery.

HTML

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="content" onclick="showMessage()">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content" onclick="showMessage()">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content" onclick="showMessage()">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content" onclick="showMessage()">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content" onclick="showMessage()">
    Content div
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('.content').on("click", function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  setTimeout(RemoveClass, 5000);
});

function RemoveClass() {
  jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
}
```

This is in Javascript I am trying but it's working only for one item.

```
 function showMessage(){
     document.querySelector(".content").classList.toggle("active");
   setTimeout(() => {
     document.querySelector(".content").classList.toggle("active");
   }, 600)
 }
```

Comment: I don't think the jQuery code will work correctly. You haven't bound `this` in the `RemoveClass` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in Javascript using ***[`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)*** property of `Event` to get the clicked element and then toggling the `active` class for that specific element. Also as an improvement to your code, you can leverage the concept of *[Event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)* by attaching a single event listener to the parent instead of attaching them to every `.content` divs.

```js
function showMessage(e) {
  const clickedElement = e.target;
  if (clickedElement.classList.contains("content")) {
    clickedElement.classList.add("active");
    setTimeout(() => {
      clickedElement.classList.remove("active");
    }, 5000);
  }
}

document.querySelector('.main-wrapper').addEventListener('click', showMessage);
```

```css
.content:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content div
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, small addition to this, can we also add a class on hover? e.g. class name is "hover"

Comment: This is what I am trying to change if need to change on click to mouseover `mainWrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', showMessage);`

Comment: Amazing!!....yes exactly  Thank you so much 

Comment: Good answer, however I would *strongly* suggest you add/remove the hover styling using CSS not JS. Then the JS code also becomes much more simple.

Comment: You are right! but this is needed something conditionally I am going to do with some user action within this div - Rory McCrossan

Comment: For some reason, when I put actual content on this div then nothing is working the hove and click are not working for me, is it same for you also? can you please check this and see.

`<div class="content" onclick="showMessage()">
        <div class="inside-wraper">Div content</div>
        <div class="toast-message">Some content</div>
</div>`

Comment: @SathishKumar why are you using `onclick=""showMessage()`? Also, the problem which you're facing now as per the above comment is now the target is not `.content` div anymore because you're adding nested elements inside the `.content` div; `inside-wrapper` for e.g.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...I have updated my nested elements, now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JS** : For all elements

```
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content')).forEach((elem) => {
   elem.addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
      event.target.classList.add('active');
      setTimeout(() => RemoveClass(event), 5000);
    });
   })

   function RemoveClass(ev) {
      ev.target.classList.remove('active');
   }
```